# Power Automate Flows

Tags: power-automate

I have been learning to use flows in Power Automate and noticed that my flows are different from most videos I have tried to follow. For example, I have under my flows option: Cloud flows, Desktop Flows, Business process flows and shared with me, whereas videos I have been watching have their options as cloud and business (same as I have) and Team flows and UI flows which I do not have. Would I be correct in thinking that the flows have just been renamed, and if so would someone be able to point out which ones changed to which?
Many thanks.
I have tried to scour the net with no luck in finding out anything about a rename.

Regards

Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned the terminologies regarding the flow names have changed. I have been trying to search the net for a proper document about the name changes but couldn't find any. To answer your question:

Team flows are now shared with me & UI flows are desktop flows

Hope I have answered your question

Regards,
RT

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation, it is certainly not easy to find the answer on this one.                    Regards, Ross